# How to save battery power for a multi-core dual-gpu-card computer in Linux

Tags: linux

I have a HP Envy4 5103t laptop, and the time of duration is impressive under pre-installed win8(4h)。However, the battery performance is very disappointed in Linux(<1h), e.g. Fedora 19 X64.

This laptop has an I7 cpu, and dual-gpu(intel/NVidia), but the Nvidia driver is not installed in Linux, so NVidia card should not be used。I don't know which one is to be blame, the cpu-core or the not-used Nvidia card.

My questions are:

- Which hardware or software is most electricity-consuming?
- Are there system-wide multi-core management software under Linux?
- Is there good power-save strategy in Linux?

Comment: i think this is the wrong forum for this question as it doesn't relate for programming.  power-user may be more appropriate - or http://unix.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Even with Nvidia enabled you should not have such battery timer. What kerner version are you using?

Comment: 3.12.7-200.fc19.x86_64 @Veske

Comment: The problem is almost certainly the nvidia card. Just because you don't have the proprietary driver installed does not mean you are not using it. You probably are but with the open source driver. Your best bet, if you don't want to use the dedicated card, is to disable it in the BIOS

Comment: There is no such option in BIOS. @terdon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need bumblebee 3, http://bumblebee-project.org/. I think the unstable version now has power management, which prior to that the gfxcard hardware itself would just default to "energy sink" whether it was being used or not.

Comment: AFAIK, bumblebee is used to use NVidia Card under multi-card situation. My question is how to save power under normal situation.

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/bumblebee#Power_management

Comment: Yes, bbswitch works.